# Which encryption algorithms are common to both ssh server and client?

Tags: ssh, encryption

I have a situation where I would like to run a complex X11 program across the network on an elder laptop through a `ssh -Y` tunnel.

The performance of the X11 program GUI (IntelliJ community edition for the record) is not as fast as I would like it to, so I am looking at speeding up the encryption of the ssh tunnel.   Preferably the "none" that was available at one time so there is no encryption but that seems not to be an option.  Hence I would like to know which algorithm are even possible for my particular setup.   I understand that multiple -v gives a lot more information but I am not certain where exactly to get what I am looking for.

So, how do I extract the encryption algorithms that client and server has in common, so I can provide the one best suited for me on future command lines?

Comment: Have you consider not to use `ssh` for tunneling all X traffic? every mouse move generate good amount of information and you really need enough bandwidth to use `X` remotely

Comment: If you're looking to have no encryption, why not just run X natively across the wire?

Comment: Read `man xhost` to share X across the LAN.

Comment: I know of xhost (which is what -Y helps with).  This may or may not be on the same LAN.  This is just a single usage scenario which triggered the question - others might be file transfers (rsync would benefit from this as well).

Comment: @roima ssh tunnelling allows for other things like port forwarding and firewall traversal.